# Cancel a password hashed with pbkdf2

Tags: security, hash, pbkdf2

I am using a pbkdf2 algorithm to hash passwords.
A random salt is generated for evey password and number of iterations are set in 
order to make the computation last about 1 second.

I am also saving salt and hash in the sambe buffer:

```
   -----------------------
   | SaltLen |     4     |
   -----------------------
   | Salt    | saltBytes |
   -----------------------
   | HashLen |     4     |
   -----------------------
   | Salt    | hashBytes |
   - ---------------------
```

My issue is that this hashed password is not linked to one user (a user can have multiple password) and i need to have the possibity to cancel a password only using the password itself.
The only way i see is to hash the password to cancel with every salt in the database until in find the same hash wich will take forever (1 second per salt).

Is there any better way to do that ?

Comment: What does _"cancel a password"_ mean?

Comment: in this case the password is a licence and i want to mark it as canceled

Comment: You will need some sort of identifier to lookup the row first. e.g. a 64 bit integer starting at 1, 2, 3. You could append it to the start of the password if needbe, but it would be in unhashed form.

Comment: i edited the question to make it clearer. the solution i go with now is to use a salt per user and not per password.

Comment: I figure out that what i have to do is to have a salt per user and not a salt per password otherwise i cannot link from the login to the matching salt. :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to treat licenses like passwords.

PBKDF2 & iterations only make sense for checks on client side. On server side they just allow to perform a DOS attack on your server. Anyway on a server you can simply add a delay of 1 second for each request.

You don't have to hash them because only licenses in your database are considered to be valid. It does not make any sense to hack your server and steal them.

For checking the right license entry you just have to prepend the database entry ID of the license to the license itself and you know exactly what entry to check.

Comment: but what can i do if i want to generate licences that will be sent to client who have like 3 months to activate them. If someone hack to my site he can get valid licences that he can use instead of the real client.

Comment: The database you have proposed in your question only makes sense if the software directly contacts the server for verifying the license. It your design is different your question gave a false impression. If you need offline verifiable licenses use asymmetric cryptography and sign your license, license name and date of expiry.